# 4-momentum of meson in nucleon scattering

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

Consider the nucleon scattering in scalar Yukawa theory.

Suppose that we are NOT using Feynman diagram (rules) and instead use the tedious Dyson- Wick more formal method.

How do we establish or derive this relationship between 4-momentum of meson and 4-momentum of nucleon:

$$
k=p_{1}-p_{1}^\prime
\tag1
$$

In particular why not

$$
k=p_{1}+p_{2}-p_{1}^\prime-p_{2}^\prime
\tag2
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this answer will satisfy you completely since I'm not familiar with the Dyson-Wick formalism.  But if I have scattering between two nucleons, with initial momenta $p_1, p_2$ and final momenta $p_1', p_2'$, and no additional particles in the final state, the conservation of momentum gives me

\begin{align}
\text{initial momentum } p &= p_1 + p_2
\\
\text{final momentum } p' &= p_1' + p_2'
\\
p-p' &= (p_1 + p_2) - (p_1' + p_2') \equiv 0.
\end{align}

So your proposed definition for $k$ vanishes identically.

Because momentum is conserved in elastic scattering, we can determine the momentum *transferred* between the two nucleons by looking at *either* of them in both the initial and the final state.
What characterizes the interaction, therefore, is the *change* in the momentum of either particle:
$$
k \equiv p_1'- p_1 = -(p_2'- p_2)
$$

The Feynman diagram suggests very strongly that we should assign this momentum to some virtual particle.  In a scattering-matrix approach, we declare our ignorance of what's happening at the scattering vertex and look for some operator that transforms our initial momenta $(p_1,p_2)$ to our final momenta $(p_1', p_2')$.
The only parameter that's available to characterize this matrix is the momentum transfer $k$.
If the matrix is associated with some scalar field, then $k$ must be the four-momentum associated with that field.